# With orchard CMS, Is it possible to add a widget to a zone in the admin?

Tags: widget, content-management-system, admin, orchardcms

Is it possible to add a widget to a zone in the admin? So you see the widget while administering. (As the admin theme uses zones too)
If not is it possible to do something similar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not currently, not exactly. If you look at the TheTree module, it does add UI elements to the admin, but not exactly a widget.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look.